# Docker - oracle.kv.FaultException: Could not contact any RepNode

Tags: java, docker, oracle-nosql

I am new to Docker and nosql, I created a Oracle Linux VM (ipAddr 192.168.10.2) on my windows machine.

Further I created docker container (on this VM ) for kvlite and run my nosql-container as below:

**$ docker run --name nosql-container -p 5000:5000 -d kvlite:latest**

followed by below commands:

**$ docker exec -it nosql-container bash**

**# java -jar lib/kvcli.jar -host localhost -port 5000**

**kv-> connect store -host localhost -port 5000 -name kvstore ;**

This works fine till here and I believe my Docker container for kvlite is up and running fine.

Now I need to create a Client Java program from my windows machine to access this kvlite (running in docker container on a VM)
To accomplish I downloaded **kvclient.jar** file and put that in my classpath.

The Java code-snippet below:

```
KVStore store = KVStoreFactory.getStore(new KVStoreConfig("kvstore", "192.168.10.2:5000"));
```

This throws an exception:

***oracle.kv.FaultException: Could not contact any RepNode at: [192.168.10.2:5000] (12.1.4.0.9)***

....

***Caused by: java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: ecfe59938ea4; nested exception is:***

Any help appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding a param --net=host when running nosql-container

```
$ docker run --name nosql-container --net=host -p 5000:5000 -d kvlite:latest
```

Now instead of IPAddress you can use VM hostname in Java Client code to access kvlite DB.

```
KVStore store = KVStoreFactory.getStore(new KVStoreConfig("kvstore", "VMHostname:5000"));
```